# rvm install rails on Mac OSX 10.7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rvm

was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as I am unable to find a previously posted answer to my question of trying to install rails on my mac mini running Lion OSX 10.7.3. I have ruby version 1.8.7 and rvm 1.12.5 but when I come to install rails using sudo gem install rails I get the following:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.0/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

The content of gem_make.out are:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
```

which did not really help me so not sure what it is I am missing? Any help or directions to help me solve this problem would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

rvm is not intended to be used with sudo except during a multi-user installation - try simply `gem install rails`. Even better, rvm now has a guided rails install,

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

Take a look at [RVM installation page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) for more details. If you're still having trouble, post the commands you're trying. The #rvm channel on irc.freenode.net is very helpful too.

In order to build Ruby and many other gems you'll need a working compiler. Unfortunately Apple has made this quite complex so there's a command in rvm to help: `rvm requirements`

Comment: Thanks Tantrix - I tried gem install rails but was told that I did not have the required permission and that's why I used sudo. I have just got into work but will have a look at the RVM installation page when I am at home this evening.

Comment: still no luck: ➜  ~  gem install rails
Fetching: json-1.7.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

Comment: and when I use sudo: Fetching: json-1.7.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.1/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment - hope you got this working! Sounds like `rvm reload` would help.

Comment: Hi no still not got this working used the above command and got RVM reloaded! but still the same original problem exists that I posted on the 8th May when using gem install rails

Comment: Ok left this for a while as was just getting no where with installing RAILs. Came across a new book called "Rails Deep Dive" which seemed like it would "hold my hand" to install rails. However just got to the magic command to install RAILs through RVM "rvm install 1.9.2". However this does not work:

Comment: Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/mark/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/mark/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

Comment: Would really like to get this solved and post the solution here as I am sure I am not the only one who is struggling.

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `sudo gem ...` it basically looses your environment settings and prevents you from using RVM.

Please follow @tantrix instructions.

Comment: Ok how do I change permissions so that I am able to install without using sudo?

Comment: are you using RVM rubies (`rvm list`), only rubies installed via RVM will work without `sudo`, if you want to use ruby 1.8.7 - jsut install it: `rvm install 1.8.7`.

Comment: just checked rvm list from the terminal and it tells me that No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'. Running RVM help does not tell me much - @mpapis how do I use RVM rubbies? Do you think that this could be the cause of not being able to install rails?

Comment: please follow @tantrix answer, in case you have problems join irc #rvm on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to install XCode on your machine to get the necessary header files for building the Rails gem. It's a huge installation, unfortunately.

There was, at one point, a way to load (e.g.) the stuff on your machine that you need to build Rails without installing XCode, but I can't seem to locate it at the moment.

Comment: And come to think of it, Apple now has command-line dev tools for download, if you have Lion.

Comment: Yeah I have installed the latest version of XCode from the apple store  prior to installing rails so that can't be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I run `rvm requirements` and it helps me install **gcc**.
But the problem still exists and only solved after I **restarted** osx.